# Just installed xcode 5 and have missing storyboards

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I am running xcode 4.6.2 for production work.

I downloaded the new Xcode 5/ios 7 sdk to see what my projects would look like. Xcode 5 installed fine, opened fine and opened one of projects fine.  I took note of the new look but made NO changes. Closed xcode 5 and when went back to xcode 4.6.2 I saw that storyboards are missing!!!

Please help. Anyone see this and no how to correct???  I still need to use Xcode 4 for production work.

Comment: Correction....physical iPhone.storyboard file is NOT missing.  My error there.  Just won't open in xcode 4.

Comment: Xcode 5 is still in beta, so many bugs can be present. Also, by its license it is not allowed to discuss it outside Apple forums.

Comment: @SteveM Check my answer, I believe that would help you. If so please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had one open in both today without issues, however it may have set the tools version in the file and that's causing XCode to trip up. If you open the Storyboard file in a text editor there's `version` and `toolsVersion`, try changing those to the correct version of the XCode 4 tools you've got installed.

Answer (score 26):

Open the Storyboard file on Xcode 5, And then:
1. Open file inspector
2. On "Interface Builder Documents" section change "Open with" to Xcode 4.6 (if it's 5.x).
3. Save, Close the project and open that with old Xcode.

It should work now.

This is same method like on earlier releases so I assume that's ok for NDA case (you can do the same thing on Xcode 4.6 to work with older version).