# The document "XXXX.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

After opening my project in the Xcode5 developer preview, errors appeared against a few .xib files when I tried to open the project in Xcode 4.5. The error text was:

```
 The document "XXXX.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive.

 Please use a newer version of Xcode. Consider changing the document's Development Target to preserve compatibility.
```

The project's development target in Xcode5 appears to be iOS 5.0.

Looking at the source code of the .xib files with errors, it is clear that the .xml structure for .xib files in Xcode5 has changed quite dramatically, and it needs to be reformatted to be backwards compatible.

Is there a way to set development targets for specific .xib files? Does anyone know how this error can be resolved?

Many thanks.

Comment: This would be a great time to suggest and try to not sound smug when saying... just take a look at your SCM log to see what Xcode changed, and revert.

Comment: How do I see the SCM log? Sorry, I don't think this was a question worthy of a mark down... I'm an amateur developer seeking help to resolving these problem, which I'm sure many other people experience.

Comment: Check my comment on answer please. And also + 1 for asking a good question.:)

Comment: For any other questions on iOS 7/Xcode 5 etc... please visit the beta section of the Apple Developer Forums. These betas are under NDA. https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/ios7_beta

Comment: Please check my answer. You don't have to use source control to solve it...

Comment: @Spinoxa. If you have backup copy of project, try to work on it

Comment: One thing I would like to add is use Xcode 5 (Final release) instead of Xcode 5 preview. This is because I encountered a Bug in Xcode 5 preview which got automatically after switching to Xcode 5 (Final release).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better and easier solution that works even if your project isn't under source control can be found here (mine):

[Just installed xcode 5 and have missing storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047409/just-installed-xcode-5-and-have-missing-storyboards/17072652#17072652)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 14):

Just open Storyboard in XCode 5, into right panel and "File Inspector" tab do:

1. edit your "Interface Builder Document" like follow:

[image]

2. Save it and open in previous XCode.

Comment: Thanks dude... But Is there any way to change all .XIBs in one time or I have to do it individually for all XIBs

Comment: I believe that you need do it with each XIB file. It happens because the files were parsed to other format when you saved it in XCode 5 for the first time.

Answer (score 13):

First of all open project with Xcode5. and then

- select XXX.xib find Interface Builder Document
- Opens in Xcode 4.6(if is 5.0)
- close project
- open it with 4.6

Answer (score 5):

It's a current problem when you open your Xcode 4.6 project with the new XCode 5.
To reuse correctly your XIB with Xcode 4.6 :

> 1 Open your project with XCode 5
>
> 2 Select your Xib to restore
>
> 3 In the File Inspector Section, in "Interface Builder Document",
>   select Xcode 4.6 in the Development's version of Document Versioning
>
> 4 Build and close
>
> 5 Reopen your project with XCode 4.6

It's possible to have some regression with elements width & size in your XIB, but it was restored successfully.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

well obviously you created your project prior to the new xcode developer preview. then you tried opening your project with the new DP and boom, it automatically changed everything in your xibs to be able to present your xibs in a higher version. easy to fix. with your xcode 4 ios 6 open the same project, then right click on the name of the xib that is not opening and select source control and from there select discard changes. that should return the xib back to the shape it was before you opened it with the new xcode DP.

let me know if you need more help but that should take care of your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't use source control so 'discard changes' took it back to a version from about 1 year ago! However, I did have a snapshot from 2 weeks ago and I should be able to rebuild the changes since then. How can I configure the project to have better source control? Is there a way to set-it up so that it auto-commits so you can always step back? Or does it have to be done manually?

Comment: You can create a local git and set it to auto refresh. The other way I use is to use snapshots. You can also adjust your source control from the settings within xcode. There might be other ways too but those are the ones I know. Good luck and if my answer helped will you please check it as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'd been using snapshots but not proper source control, but I shall do that more from now on. Thanks for your help, and thanks also for reverting that idiotic -1 vote on a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Check my answer, You don't have to use source control to fix that. Although using source control is a good practice always.

Comment: using source control will ensure the saftey of the project and a point to return to. as i said in my previouse comments there are other ways, but i use source control since it providees more safety for me. and as you mentioned is a very good practice.

Comment: @Spinoxa You can setup a "Behavior" in Xcode preferences that creates a snapshot after each successful build (for example). I think the snapshot feature actually uses git internally, too.

Answer (score 3):

1. First you have to open your's project with newer version of Xcode.
2. Right click on XXX.xib file and select "Show File Inspector."
3. Go to Interface Builder Document.
4. Change Development option with older version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Once I used to manage a project with XCode 5 xibs in XCode 4. I split xibs for each XCode version and made this build script that compiles xib to nib and place that nib them inside the app

```
#get SDK version
SDK_VERSION=$(echo $SDKROOT | sed -e 's/.*iPhone\(OS\)*\(Simulator\)*\([0-9]*.[0-9]*\).sdk/\3/')

if [ $SDK_VERSION == '7.0' ]; then
   echo 'Current SDK is 7.0'

   ibtool --compile ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app/output.nib ${PROJECT_DIR}/ProjectFolder/input.xib.xib 

   echo 'Copied nibs to' ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app
else
   echo 'Current SDK is not 7.0 (SDK is' $SDK_VERSION')'
fi
```