# Project build failed in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Only for a specific project xcode showing `project build failed` without any error.

Which was working fine till yesterday.

Without any change it is not working today.

What is the issue?

What can I do?

Comment: check your provisioning profiles didnt get expire.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the derived data (Organizer->Projects / cmd + shift + 2) and then cleaning (cmd+shift+K)

Comment: provisioning profiles didn't expire.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363564/xcode-4-build-failed-no-issues

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In your Xcode navigator, click on the **Show the Log Navigator** tab.

[image]

This tab will contain the build logs for each time your build/compile the application. When an error occurs, this will show you details. There is an expand button to check the details causing the error.  Check the steps until it fails, see if anything fishy is happening during the build process. Usually in error cases the build process will freeze/quit at a particular source file.

[image]

Usually I have seen that restarting Xcode would clear its error cache and any stray errors will go away. Also as a quick check create a new sample app and try building it. If you get errors building this app as well, I'd suggest you reinstall the Xcode. If this builds properly, there is definitely issue with your project files/code. In that case you need to add more details in your question.

Comment: @salim Is this helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I can not see any issue into log navigator. Just showing `project build failed`.

Comment: @Salim Are there any steps printing in the log which shows some source files? Could you share a screenshot of log navigator?

Comment: Oh great answer I have found the issue in navigator. That is: The document "DialpadController.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive.

Comment: @Salim Try this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156004/the-document-xxxx-xib-could-not-be-opened-could-not-read-archive

Comment: @Salim 1. Right click on XXX.xib file and select "Show File Inspector."
2. Go to Interface Builder Document.

3. Change Development option with the version of Xcode you are using.

Comment: I got this error too. I'm changing my mac's date to test a function. I'm setting it on a future date. If I compile and build and there's no error, xcode keeps a log of it. When I revert to the correct date and there's an error, xcode, I think, searches for the 'latest' build details/errors and gets my 'future' build data so I can't get my build error data for 'now'.

Comment: @Salim I am able to see the images.

Answer (score 1):

Find the error by clicking on this icon at your xcode:

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question?