# Xcode 4 won't allow me to open the storyboard edited in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, xcode4.6, xcode5

I have a problem: I can't open the Storyboard file in Xcode 4.6 after having used the app in Xcode 5. What should I do to open it in Xcode 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Just installed xcode 5 and have missing storyboards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047409/just-installed-xcode-5-and-have-missing-storyboards)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: Follow the red steps on the right]
Go back to your Storyboard in Xcode 5, then go to the right pane under the `File Inspector tab` (select it from the top, it's the icon with the little blank sheet). You will find a section called `Interface Builder Document`. There, set `Opens in` as `Xcode 4.6` instead of `Default (5.0)`. It will also change the way your user interface will look like, since Xcode 4.X doesn't support iOS 7 SDK, which contains the User Interface components (known as flat UI).

Though, you can use Xcode 5 to develop for iOS 6 (I do). **EDIT** As Idan said, you won't be able to submit apps for the App Store from a beta version of Xcode, so until its official 'stable' release comes out

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here:
[Just installed xcode 5 and have missing storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047409/just-installed-xcode-5-and-have-missing-storyboards/17072652#17072652)

Btw, You can develop for iOS5,6 etc. with Xcode 5 but you cannot submit the app with a beta Xcode. So you would have to wait or use old Xcode to submit.