# To convert the xcode 5 project into xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Can any  one  know how to convert the xcode 5 project into xcode 4.
  I am trying to open xcode 5 project  into xcode 4.6 and click on the nib file xcode automatically close. even not run on simulator.
  I am googling lot but not found any such link or blog. If any one have a link or some blog
 for refrence.

thanks in advance

Comment: Launch it again with 5 then from file inspector downgrade the document versioning.

Comment: Set your deployment target to 6.x and you might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually quite easy as I think. There are some ways to do it but here is the simplest one.

At first change the view "as" mode of the `nib` or `storyboard` like in this post
[Xcode 4 won't allow me to open the storyboard edited in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264571/xcode-4-wont-allow-me-to-open-the-storyboard-edited-in-xcode-5)

The second step is to open the `storyboard` file with TextEdi...

[image]

and changing the highlighted value from "**3.0**" to "**2.0**"

[image]

If something doesn‘t works well, just let me know.

Good luck.

Noah