# not able to open storyboard file in xcode 4.6.3 after opening the project in xcode 5

Tags: uistoryboard, xcode5, xcode4.6.3

i am not able to open storyboard file in xcode 4.6.3 after opening the project in xcode 5.It shows the error

```
The document "MyStoryboard.storyboard" cannot be opened.could not read archive
```

I have not kept any backups and need the project to be edited in 4.6.3 .Can i revert it somehow to open in this version

Comment: Can't believe you did not use Git to keep local versions of your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 won't allow me to open the storyboard edited in Xcode 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264571/xcode-4-wont-allow-me-to-open-the-storyboard-edited-in-xcode-5)

Answer (score 1):

Now go back and read the Seed Note on the developer site. 
It says exactly this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the version of storyboard from 3.0 to 2.0.
by following way.

1    In the "File Inspector" select the storyboard.

2    Right click it go to open as.

3    Go to source code.

4    Changed the version from 3.0 to 2.0.