# The document “XXXX.xib” could not be opened. My xcode version is 4.6.2 & below . Is have any alternative solution without install xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, xib

I have downloaded sample app from internet When ever i executes the application. It is showing an error that was

**The document "xxxxxx.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive.**

Please use a newer version of Xcode. Consider changing the document's Development Target to preserve compatibility

i know why i am getting this error that is created latest version of xcode 5 but i don't have xcode 5 because of  my MAC OS
X is lion.

**Is have any alternative solution without install xcode 5?**

I have used xcode 4.6 and below vesion of xcode.
Any interface builder is not able to open.
I have tried to open with 4.6.2, 4.5.2, 4.3.3 as well but no use.

Comment: ` Consider changing the document's Development Target to preserve compatibility` have you try it?

Comment: @johnMa yes i tried Change Development option is Disabled

Comment: We had the same problem. We could only solve it by setting the version of the xib to Xcode 4. Unfortunately you need Xcode 5 for that.

Comment: I don't believe there is much you can do.  You'll have to use a newer version of Xcode.

Comment: Use svn from their you can revert the file :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .xib files created in new xcode 5 differs from the ones created in previous xcode versions. Since Apple moved to new method for making .xib or storyboard in xcode 5, older xcodes cannot read the newer .xibs. So there is no other way, you have to go only for xcode 5.

After installing xcode 5 you may try to make them backward compatible--> see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281073/cant-open-project-in-xcode-4-6-after-opening-in-5-0)

Comment: Nope. It requires OS X version 10.8.4 minimum. You can go for a free upgrade to OS X 10.9 Maverics.