# App crash on run Xcode 5.0

Tags: ios6, storyboard, xcode4.2, ios7, xcode5

I have made a simple app using Storyboard in Xcode 4.6.2, and it has worked perfectly all the time until now. Recently i started developing in Xcode 5.0 (beta1), and it worked perfectly when running. But when I was going to submit it to the App Store I got an error message, because Apple isn't allowing apps to be published from Xcode beta version. I therefore opened the xcode project in Xcode 4.6.2, and set the storyboard to work with that version of xcode and ios 6.1. But now it crashes when i try to run the app. Both in the simulator and on my iPhones (4S running 6.1 and 5 running 7).

This is the error message I get:

http://bildr.no/view/TytRaTNN

Have someone else had problems with this? Or do someone know how to fix this? Thank you. I have already sent it to App Store, but I think I have to reject the binary because of this bug.

Thank you!

Comment: NDA means use Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Try cleaning the targets (shift+cmd+K). There might be something left over that was built with Xcode5.

Comment: What crash error message/stack trace are you seeing in the debugger?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I have updated the question with the error message.

Comment: Did you do a `raise(SIGABRT);` somewhere?

Comment: Haven't seen SIGABRT for a long time other than in failed assertions. There is no stack trace or further info in Xcode to look at?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I have updated the question again. Look at the screenshot, and see if you can get more information from that.

Comment: @JosteinLiverød This is very simple to solve, Check my answer.
this isn't relevant to the NDA because that happens with every new release, See my answer for more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operative part seems to be;

```
Could not find a storyboard named '<strange character>' in bundle NSBundle...
```

It most likely means that the name set for your main storyboard is messed up (I can repeat the exact symptoms on a new project, just changing the storyboard name to a non existing one).

Start by checking that the correct story board name is set as "Main Storyboard" (click the project, then the Summary tab, iPhone should be visible, iPad is farther down). When that is set correctly, a clean/rebuild (as Alex Blundell pointed out in the comments) is required to rebuild with the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has a super simple solution.

The problem is that Xcode transform your Storyboard file to be edited with new Xcode version, You just need to reverse that (This is not under the NDA because that happens with every new release).

Check my answer here:
[Just installed xcode 5 and have missing storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047409/just-installed-xcode-5-and-have-missing-storyboards/17072652#17072652)