# How do I fix a project opened in xcode5 dp3 by accident?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5

At some point I opened a project in xcode5 that was created in xcode4.  Now I can build/run because of a storyboard error.  XCode4 simply wont run it, it says:

> The document Storyboard.storyboard could not be opened, could not read
>   archive.  Please use a newer version of XCode.  Consider changing the
>   documents development target to preserve compatibility.

So I go to XCode5 I get this:

> 2013-07-19 10:38:11.340 ibtoold[756:707] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION
>   FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3697.3/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:673
>   Details:  Failed to compute auto layout status IBLayoutConstraint,
>   IBUILabel, IBUITableViewCell, and IBUITableViewCellContentView.
>
> Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS
>   Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this
>   issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface
>   Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash
>   report.

and when I try to open the storyboard, XCode5 crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out an older version of the project from your source control?  Use Time Machine?

Comment: Did you look at all of the duplicate questions shown under "Related"?

Comment: @rmaddy yes but they all talk about selecting the storyboard and modifying Document Versioning which is not an option for me.  Im unable to select the storyboard without it crashing (XCode5) or having Document Versioning greyed out (XCode4)

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the bit about the crashing in Xcode 5 when I voted on the duplicate. That sounds like something you can't recover from easily, and might be something you want to file a bug report with Apple on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening the XML and removing the Boolean for AL and then re-adding it.

Answer (score 4):

Open the Storyboard/Xib file on Xcode 5, And then: 1. Open file inspector 2. On "Interface Builder Documents" section change "Open with" to Xcode 4.6 (if it's 5.x). 3. Save, Close the project and open that with old Xcode.

It should work now.

This is same method like on earlier releases so I assume that's ok for NDA case (you can do the same thing on Xcode 4.6 to work with older version).

Or read my answer here: [Just installed xcode 5 and have missing storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047409/just-installed-xcode-5-and-have-missing-storyboards/17072652#17072652)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The same thing can happen for XIBs as well, and the same fix applies.

Comment: @DougMcBride Yep, Xib& Storyboard are same for this matter. thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Open the storyboard in Xcode 5. In the file inspector on the right, you should see something that says "Document Versioning". There you should set the deployment level to iOS 6.1 and set it to open the file with Xcode 4.6.2. After you do this, you should be able to open and build the storyboard in Xcode 4 again.

Comment: Document Versioning is greyed out :(

Comment: It's a file format versioning issue with the storyboard file itself (see other answer), not a project-level issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but could not even open the storyboard - Xcode 5.0.1 and 5.0.2 kept crashing with

ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3697.3/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:673 Details: Failed to compute auto layout status IBLayoutConstraint, IBUILabel, IBUITableViewCell, and IBUITableViewCellContentView.

The solution in my case was to open project and storyboard with Xcode 5.0 (the last version the storyboard opened in) and to search for a table problem.

After some time searching, I found a second table that must have been inserted in error behind the real table. It had no height or width so was only spotted in the inspector on theleft hand side (see picture). I deleted this rogue table and then loaded in 5.0.2 and life was good!

[image]