# Can't Run my iOS App from Xcode 4.6 after installing Xcode 5

Tags: xcode4.6, xcode5

I installed resently Xcode 5 with iOS 7 SDK on my Mac OS 10.8.
the problem is i can't any more run my iOS app from Xcode 4.6, here's the errors:
- when I run the app from Xcode, after build I have this message:
"can't find the existing path [myproject.app path]"
and the file exist in the specified path.
- when I generate the ipa and install it by iTune I have this message:
"not supported device".

my app works fine before installing the new Xcode (5 + iOS 7 SDK)
any one have a solution?

Thanks

Rachid

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution!

Xcode 5 like any previous change some formats. To my knowledge the most common issues are:
1. changing the Xib/Storyboard file, You can check my answer here for solution: [How do I fix a project opened in xcode5 dp3 by accident?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751319/how-do-i-fix-a-project-opened-in-xcode5-dp3-by-accident/17756180#17756180)

2. It can change the framework path format (you should get an error when compiling), To solve this check my answer here: [sentestingkit/sentestingkit.h' file not found on Xcode 4.6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992028/sentestingkit-sentestingkit-h-file-not-found-on-xcode-4-6-x/17992029#17992029)

If those both doesn't work for you please add more details and I would love to help.