# sentestingkit/sentestingkit.h' file not found on Xcode 4.6.x

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4, xcode5

I've got this error which took me a while to solve.

Problem is that the Xcode 4.6.x doesn't recognise this library suddenly without me changing anything.

Because I assume many of you would have same problem I post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this issue is pretty simple. This happened because I've been used Xcode 5 which apparently change the style of the "Framework search path" on the build settings.

It change is a way that each '"' mark converted into '\"'. So to solve it just go there on Xcode 4.6.x and remove the '\' before the '"'.

I'm sure it could change more things there so add it here if you get another changes between those versions.

Comment: I am migrating from Xcode 4.6.1 to Xcode 5 and i m getting the same error as you described. As I am new user and i dont know much about settings so I am not getting what you are telling. Can you describe it in detail.

Comment: Go to your target -> Build settings and search for "Framework search path".

Comment: i know that, my question is how to convert that path, for example, i have following path written in Framework search path in my app(Xcode 4.6), now what should i change in that path so it will work in Xcode 5. My Path is as                                         $(inherited)\"$(SYSTEM_APPS_DIR)/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks\" $(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)

Comment: Remove all backslashes.

Comment: Tried as u have told, but still not working....